# Changed monitor and screen resolution got lower

Tags: bash, display-resolution, monitor

I switched monitor of my Lubuntu machine, and the resolution is low now, however the monitor **make and model is the same** as the previous one.

Considering the fact that I didn't change any config on my Lubuntu, how I can increase the resolution. I played around with Monitor settings menu, but as far as I looked for, there is no option for changing the resolution. The output of `$ xrandr` is shown below.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

---

UPDATE

There is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and when I run following commands on console (<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>):

```
$ sudo service lightdm stop
$ cd /etc/X11
$ sudo Xorg -configure
```

I receive the following message:

`No devices to configure. Configuration failed.`
`(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.`

---

UPDATE

I ran

```
i@i-desktop:~$ gtf 1280 720 60 

  # 1280x720 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 44.76 kHz; pclk: 74.48 MHz
  Modeline "1280x720_60.00"  74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync
```

then:

```
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"  74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync
i@i-desktop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x720_60.00 (0x9a) 74.480MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1336 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.76KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
```

And then I ran

```
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x720_60.00
```

Now the resolution is higher but now it has horizontal and vertical offset, i.e. the screen doesn't fit the monitor.

---

UPDATE

I set the resolution to 1920x1080 60Hz and my monitor popped up a message saying that the **optimum resolution is `1440x900 60Hz`**. So I ran the following commands and the problem is solved now:

```
i@i-desktop:~$ gtf 1440 900 60

  # 1440x900 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 55.92 kHz; pclk: 106.47 MHz
  Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync

i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1280x720_60.00  60.00  
   1368x768_60.00  60.00  
   1920x1080_60.00  60.00  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1440x900_60.00 (0xbb) 106.470MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.92KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  60.00Hz
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1280x720_60.00  60.00  
   1368x768_60.00  60.00  
   1920x1080_60.00  60.00  
   1440x900_60.00  60.00  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
i@i-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1440x900      60.00*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1280x720_60.00  60.00  
   1368x768_60.00  60.00  
   1920x1080_60.00  60.00  
   1440x900_60.00  60.00  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What is your preferred resolution ?

Comment: @Liso I prefer the resolution of my previous monitor which was higher than current one, but I'm not sure what resolution it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open terminal and type `xrandr` it will display a list of possible resolutions for your current connection to the monitor.

You can read more about `xrandr` [here](https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html). In particular adding modes.

To add a mode you must first create a new `modeline` using `gtf` or `cvt`. Copy the details from the modeline into `xrandr --newmode`. Then use `xrandr` to add that mode to your desired output. Finally set the mode using `xrandr -s`.

```
gtf 1366 768 60.00
xrandr --newmode 1368x768-60  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768-60
xrandr -s 1368x768-60
```

It's important to note that if the new setting does not work properly or you are unhappy setting the new mode using `xrandr -s` then you can return to original by using `xrandr -s 0` which will return to default.

Screen resolutions also have different formats and common resolutions can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_Video_Standards2.svg). Some formats or resolutions cause the screen to overhang and it may just be a case of having to work out which ones fit and which ones don't, but by staying within the range of a format that works (eg. 16:9, 16:10) then you should go up in working style.

Comment: Added the output of `$ xrandr` to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was connected by VGA

Comment: I'm not quite sure what was the resolution of my previous monitor

Comment: @user7312233 I also have no /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: I wonder if you can run `$ sudo X -configure`. Does it work fine for you? It is giving me errors like `No devices to configure`

Comment: Mine does show devices to configure have you tried my updated answer?

Comment: Sure, I tried to add new modes with `gtf 1366 768 60` and then using output to run `sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"  74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746  -HSync +Vsync` and then running `sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x720_60.00` and now the resolution got higher but the screen doesn't fit the monitor, I mean there are horizontal and vertical offsets.

Comment: Will look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

After upgrading to Linux Mint 20.2 Uma, my display resolution would automatically go to 1024x768_60.00.

I had been attempting to set xrandr permanently with resolution 1920x1080-60 and had created a:

1. .Xprofile folder in my home folder
2. an external_monitor_resol.sh file
3. the following was included in the external_monitor_resol.sh file:

- xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
- xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
- xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"

source: Linux Mint Forums https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=274540

I believe due to the fact that the installation of the VGA went from the PC to an HDMI Adapter and HDMI to my 1080 TV Monitor, I was having to use xrandr every time I rebooted or shutdown startup.  I could also click on the display icon and the resolution would change to the 1920x1080-60.  When I ran xrandr, the resolution would change to 1920x1080_60.00, but the starting output was 1024x768_60.00.

It was not until I had added this line:

xrandr -s 1920x1080-60

per the above instructions by Ynot, that the resolution became permanent after reboot, and I no longer had to run xrandr or click on the display icon to have the resolution change to the correct resolution of 1920x1080-60.

Thank you!